# CompositeControl with DataGrid as child control. Not firing Update / Cancel events

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to create a CompositeControl that has a DataGrid as a Child control in it. I got the Edit command to work, but the Update (i deleted the update event code for this example to make it easier to read) and the Cancel events don't get fired. I really don't have a clue anymore what I am doing wrong, and Google doesn't offer me with tutorials on this topic (Datagrid as a child control of a CompositeControl). Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ConfigEditor runat=server></{0}:ConfigEditor>")]
public class ConfigEditor : CompositeControl, INamingContainer
{
    private DataGrid data;

    public ConfigEditor()
    { }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();
        data = new DataGrid();
        data.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        data.BorderWidth = 0;
        data.EnableViewState = false;
        data.CssClass = "table table-condensed table-striped";
        data.EditCommand += new DataGridCommandEventHandler(data_EditCommand);
        data.CancelCommand += new DataGridCommandEventHandler(data_CancelCommand);

        PopulateData();

        Controls.Add(data);

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    void data_CancelCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        data.EditItemIndex = -1;
        PopulateData();
    }

    void data_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        data.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        PopulateData();
    }

    void PopulateData()
    {
        var myConfigManager = SessionState.AppContext.GetProvider<ConfigManager>();
        data.DataSource = myConfigManager.LoadConfigItemsDt();
        data.Columns.Clear();

        TemplateColumn tcKey = new TemplateColumn();
        tcKey.HeaderText = "KEY";
        tcKey.ItemTemplate = new DefaultItemTemplate("KEY");
        tcKey.EditItemTemplate = new DefaultItemTemplate("KEY");
        data.Columns.Add(tcKey);

        TemplateColumn tcString = new TemplateColumn();
        tcString.HeaderText = "String";
        tcString.ItemTemplate = new DefaultItemTemplate("ValueString");
        tcString.EditItemTemplate = new EditTextBoxTemplate("ValueString");
        data.Columns.Add(tcString);

        TemplateColumn tcButtons = new TemplateColumn();
        tcButtons.ItemTemplate = new EditControlTemplate("KEY");
        tcButtons.EditItemTemplate = new UpdateControlTemplate("KEY");
        data.Columns.Add(tcButtons);

        data.DataBind();
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        data.RenderControl(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by following this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11735/Managing-ViewState-Rendering-and-Events-in-Composi

I basically forgot to bind the data only when there was no postback and i messed up the order of the creation of the datagrid

Answer (score 1):

A couple of remarks that may or may not help:

- I'd consider using `GridView` rather than `DataGrid`.  `DataGrid` is obsolete since .NET 2.0.
- One oddity in your code is that you're calling `DataBind` from `CreateChildControls` (CreateChildControls > PopulateData > DataBind).  What's more, you're calling it before adding the DataGrid to the control tree, which means that any changes made during binding won't be persisted to ViewState. I'm not really sure what impact this would have without seeing more code, but I would certainly consider moving DataBind() out of CreateChildControls.